# How to call helper in view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a helper and save it as MY_skm_helper.php,
and call it in my view like this

`$this->load->helper('MY_skm');`

but it shows error like this:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/my_skm_helper.php

Comment: You mustn't load helpers in your view. You're breaking the `MVC` pattern. Instead think of what your helper does and prepare your data in the controller, before sending it to the view.

Comment: Strongly agree with @IvankaTodorova. Use controller for load view. Only show data to view. No calculation at all

Comment: Try load it in controller as view might not extends to helper class.

Comment: i also try it to call from controller but same error occur.

Answer (score 0):

First rename your helper with `my_skm_helper.php`

load your helper in controller better in `__construct`

```
$this->load->helper('my_skm');
```

Comment: have you placed your helper file within application/helper ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to override a helper? if that's a custom helper, try removing the 'MY_' prefix then load it using its name without '_helper'

ex:
   rename the my_skm_helper to skm_helper. then, load it like this in one of your controllers.
   $this->load->helper('skm');

Comment: i made custom helper MY_skm_helper,but its agian show error same above i mentioned.i am using codeigniter 3.0